# How to model time dependent invariants?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have an invariant, something like if I raise one event, then I cannot raise the same event for the same user again for an hour. So the invariant depends on the past and eventual consistency does not work for it. I could keep the past in memory, but that would not work if I want to scale out horizontally. I am curious how problems like this are solved with DDD?

**clarification**

I decided to add some clarification, maybe it will be easier to answer the question with it. In my application I have a value for each user. That value has dependencies and every time those dependencies are updated the new value is calculated by an algorithm. When the value reaches a threshold, then an event should be raised. When that event is raised, then I should notify the user. I don't want to send the notification 2-3-5 times for the same user, because it would be very annoying for them, so I decided to add a cooldown time, for example 1 hour to prevent that.

So I have the upper scenario, which I can easily solve by storing a lastNotified property for the user in my current application. Let's assume that the application grows and I have to scale it horizontally, so I will run the same code on multiple servers. If so, it can happen that I send a UserNotified event to the queue for processing from one server and shortly after that I calculate the value again on a different server. The other server won't know about the recent changes, so it will raise an UserNotified event too and I will end up with 2 UserNotified events on the queue for the same user, because of eventual consistency. Ofc. I could compensate for the second event or check the cooldown time again, but in the long run I can end up with an event storage full of compensations or useless events if this becomes something frequent. Is there a good solution for this?

A possible solution I thought of would be having a service which would store the userId - lastNotified pairs and if I want to update those pairs I need to send the lastNotified value I read from the service last time. If that value changed meanwhile, then the update will fail. Only after a successful update can I raise the UserNotified event, process it and send the actual notification. I am not sure that I am comfortable with this solution, but I don't know of anything better.

Comment: Is it an invariant or is it a business rule ?

Comment: Let the event be raised, but have the thing processing events enforce the rule. Then you can shard the processor by user and it wont run out of memory

Comment: @Ewan I would end up with the exact same problem plus a bad domain model if I'd do that. :-)

Comment: @Christophe I think it is an invariant. The application monitors a value per user and that value has dependencies. When those dependencies change, then the value is updated based on an algorithm. When the value reaches a certain threshold, then the user is notified. I don't want to send the notification twice, so I thought I add a 1 hour or longer cooldown time. The actual code will be even more complicated, because I don't want to send notifications at night and if the value does not go below the threshold during the cooldown period, then I don't want to send the notification again.

Comment: @Christophe I think these notification events and the rules related to them should be part of the domain, because the whole app is about notifying the users that something is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to scale out horizontally. I am curious how problems like this
>   are solved with DDD?

It's hard to talk about things in the abstract so lets assume that your event is:

```
user withdraws money
```

and the invariant you want to enforce is:

```
user can only withdraw money once per hour
```

Difficulty : `distributed system`

As you point out in your question, the rule requires knowledge of all other transactions, or at least the last transaction, so where ever you enforce the rule can't be distributed.

This presumably conflicts with your `User` domain model, which you want to run in a distributed manner for other reasons.

The way to resolve this is to have your distributed part of the system raise an event

`user requests to withdraw money`

and a non distributed event processor

`withdrawal request processor`

This processor, being non distributed can keep an atomic record of transactions and enforce the `only one per hour` rule. Emitting `user withdraws money` or `withdrawal denied` events accordingly. While allowing you to keep your domain model distributed.

How do you scale out the non distributed processor though? You don't want it to become a bottleneck.

Because the rule is enforced per user you can have a processor per user, or more likely a relational database which is sharded by groups of users and a pool of processors per group.

As your user number grow you horizontally scale by adding more shards and processor pools inorder to keep each relational database's performance within acceptable limits.

This doesn't break DDD or your Domain model as you have the concept of Domain Events to handle this kind of thing

Comment: I edited my question meanwhile, but I think I got the same conclusion. We need to add immediate consistency somewhere to the system, otherwise this problem cannot be solved. Good thought to scale it out per user. I thought about scaling it by geolocation, but that can be changed if somebody travels, which can lead to conflicts. This would be an interesting question too... Thanks for the answer! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Time is an input:

> There are four principle inputs to a game: keystrokes, mouse moves, network packets, and time. (If you don't consider time an input value, think about it until you do - it is an important concept) -- [John Carmack, 1998](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ESWAT/john-carmack-plan-archive/master/by_day/johnc_plan_19981014.txt)

If you think about the application and the domain model as distinct abstractions, you'll see that they understand time differently.

The application understands how to get time (ex: by reading the system clock), but doesn't know what it is for.

The domain model knows how to track time provided to it, and do calculations with those values, but doesn't know how to get the time.  It has no notion of the passage of time - time is just another discrete thing that is occasionally updated via an input.

Which means that in your application logic, you are going to have some code that looks like

```
domainModel.onTick(now())
```

So all of the computation, and all of the bookkeeping, is done within the domain model.

> if I raise one event, then I cannot raise the same event for the same user again for an hour.

```
domainModel.onTick(now())
for e : domainModel.events(eventFactory):
    raiseEvent(e)
```

So the domain model can compute all of the events that should be raised, given the current time.

When you have time dependence, you may also have scheduling -- the domain model should compute more stuff in the future.  That often looks like telling the application when to reschedule another run

```
// ...
for j : domainModel.jobsToSchedule(jobFactory):
    scheduler.submit(j)
```

The use of `eventFactory` and `jobFactory` here are motivated by separation of concerns; the domain model understands the *semantics* of jobs and events, but the implementation details of the plumbing belong somewhere else.

> I have a value, that is dependent on other values. When the dependencies change, the value is recalculated. When the value reaches a threshold and event is raised. After that the system should not raise another event for an hour.

I would expect that the waiting happens *outside*, where the reads and the clock are.  The decisions (like, what are we waiting for) belong on the inside.

```
// ...
if domainModel.iNeedAnX():
    x = sourceOfX.read()
    domainModel.onX(now(), x)
```

For more detail on this sort of idea in a real problem, see Cory Benfield's [Building Protocol Libraries the Right Way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cC3_jGwl_U)

Comment: Interesting. So I guess that means, that I have a loop that updates the time and when the time updates I check if all the conditions are met to raise an event. Should I add the loop to the domain model or it should update the time from outside? This is a good solution, especially for a game, but my case is somewhat different. It it something like, I have a value, that is dependent on other values. When the dependencies change, the value is recalculated. When the value reaches a threshold and event is raised. After that the system should not raise another event for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

An invariant that varies depending on time is not an invariant:

> **INVARIANT**: An ASSERTION about some design element that must be **true at
>   all times**, except during specifically transient situations such as the
>   middle of the execution of a method, or the middle of an uncommitted
>   database transaction.
>   Eric Evans

The situation that you describe is not transient, since the two events are raised independently.

You describe in fact a rule about what event is acceptable or not. This rule can be translated into an [invariant at the  aggregate](https://medium.com/serialized-io/event-sourcing-explained-part-2-some-things-you-should-know-about-a929940c1d5c).  This means that you have to keep track in your aggregate the date of the last event of the timed events.

In this case your invariant becomes: “The timestamp of event X affecting aggregate A must be at least one hour after the last time stamp for that event in A”

Answer (score 1):

If you have a massively distributed system you can think about using **Kafka** with **[Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)**.

With this you get everything out of the box with a couple of lines code, i.e. distributed *stateful* operations. You just send all events as they are generated and don't worry about the time aspect. You essentially send (userId, event) to a topic.

Then you create another processor which gets those events *and* keeps state for all users, i.e. the last time a notification was sent. Forwards events to a third component only if sufficient time has passed, or sends out the notification itself.

Both of these components can be arbitrarily distributed. Kafka makes sure that all events relating to one user always goes to the same instance (even better, the same *thread*!), and if an instance fails all state is transferred to another suitable instance where the events will arrive after the transfer is complete.

I would however add, that if you are not massively scaling, but have 2 or 3 nodes at most, it may be not worth the effort. Just put it in a database or some central component.

Comment: Currently I don't scale massively, I was just curious how to solve this when I need it. Kafka sounds interesting, I'll read about it, thanks!